# Module 'collections' has no attribute 'Hashable' error

Tags: collections, hashable

I ran one of my chatbot codes, but it said there was an error:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 126, in construct_mapping
if not isinstance(key, collections.Hashable):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Hashable'

I'm not sure what this means can someone help me come up with a solution?

this is my code:
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('MyBot')

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.english')

def get_response(user_input):
response = chatbot.get_response(user_input)
return str(response)

print("Hello! I'm your chatbot. Type 'exit' to end the conversation.")
while True:
user_input = input("You: ")

```
if user_input.lower() == 'exit':
    print("Bot: Goodbye!")
    break

response = get_response(user_input)
print("Bot:", response)
```